# Find webpage element that gets added dynamically through JS, using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, dom

I am new to VBA. I am working on some VBA forms that interact with a website in IE. For standard websites with just HTML elements the below works for me to pass on data from my VBA form to the website - I tested this successfully with different pages.

My problem now is that I have a website with a **textarea that has both an ID and a name** but is not part of the website's basic HTML and instead gets **added dynamically through a JS** event upon click of a button. 
Because of this my standard VBA code doesn't work as it cannot find the corresponding element on the website.

Is there a **different way to find dynamically added elements on a website** ? In my case this is also the only textarea element on this site.

**My code:**

```
Dim objDataObject As New DataObject
Dim objIE As Object
Dim varUrl As String

objDataObject.SetText TxtSql.Text
objDataObject.PutInClipboard

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

varUrl = "https://myurl.com/"

objIE.Navigate varUrl
objIE.Visible = True

While objIE.busy
    DoEvents
Wend

With objIE.Document
    .getElementById("myId").Value = objDataObject.GetText(1)
End With
```

Comment: Can you get the event to fire first then find it by Name or ID?

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. In theory I would need to click a button on the previous webpage for this and then search the textarea on this new, dynamically created page but I cannot figure out how to make this work in VBA. It seems .Click does not work with the button's ID or I used it wrong or there is another way in VBA. :)

Comment: So .Click isn't clicking? Did you try firing OnClick? E.g. element.FireEvent("OnClick"). Can you see which events are triggered with something like firebug?